# Saving an instance of an object having an issue with decimal on SQLite

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin

I'm trying to save an instance of an apr object, below is my save routine

```
 void SaveButton_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        MainWindowViewModel APR = new MainWindowViewModel()
        {
            ProductName = proName.Text,
            TotalAPR = totAPR,
            Total = tot,
            Monthly = mon

        };
```

ProductName is a string property. TotalAPR, Total & Monthly are all decimals. I understand you can't save decimals in SQLite but is there a work around. ProName, totAPR, tot & mon are all x:Name. Currently getting underlines for all except the obvious ProductName.

Comment: "getting underlines" in the editors hint that you have an error.  If you hover over it or build your project it will show you specific error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if `totAPR` is a UI control (presumably an `Entry`) then you need to get it's value (a string) and parse it.

```
    var APR = Decimal.Parse(totAPR.Text);

    MainWindowViewModel APR = new MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        ProductName = proName.Text,
        TotalAPR = APR,
        ...
    };
```